# How to calculate limit of series

Tags: calculus, limits, exponential-function

I have many limits for homework that I dont know how to solve them.

I tried many things, but dont have any idea.
Hope you can help me

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} n*c^n  $$ when
$$\lvert c\rvert < 1$$

one more limit is:
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\sqrt[n]e + \sqrt[n] {e^2} + \sqrt[n]{e^3}+...+\sqrt[n]{e^{2n}}}{n}$$

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

HINT:

For the first problem, since $c<1$, define a number $x>0$ by $c=\frac{1}{1+x}$.  Then,

$$nc^n=\frac{n}{(1+x)^n}$$

Now expand the numerator using the binomial theorem.

For the second problem, recognize the sum is the Riemann sum for $\int_0^2 e^x\,dx$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Take the logarithm of $nc^n$:
$$
\log(n)+n\log(c)=n\,\overbrace{\left(\frac{\log(n)}{n}+\log(c)\right)}^{\text{eventually }\le\frac12\log(c)\,\lt\,0}
$$
Use L'Hôpital to find
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log(n)}{n}
$$

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment? What is wrong with this hint? If I don't want to explain more without some effort on the part of the OP.

Comment: The only thing I would criticize is the wrong accent on the "o" of L'Hôpital. Probably not what the downvoter had in mind.

Comment: @ClementC.: I hit the alt+u instead of the alt+i. They are right next to each other and my eyes are not quite used to my Retina display.

Comment: But anyway, that is at best a minor nitpick.

Comment: @ClementC.: I understand. I have added a little more explanation. Perhaps the downvoter did not see where I was pointing.